# Creating a Custom Camera Preview Overlay with Ionic & Capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, camera, overlay, preview, capacitor

I am trying to create custom camera with overlay. I have tried https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JA8k738i9jQ&t=385s tutorial. Actually this tutorials output i needed. But when i click on the open camera it's opening native camera instead the in app camera. Am i doing anything wrong. this is my code. Thanks in advance.

camera.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

const { CameraPreview } = Plugins

import { CameraPreviewOptions, CameraPreviewPictureOptions } from '@capacitor-community/camera-preview';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-camera',
  templateUrl: './camera.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./camera.page.scss'],
})
export class CameraPage implements OnInit {
  image = null;
  cameraActive = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openCamera() {
    const cameraPreviewOptions: CameraPreviewOptions = {
      position: 'rear',
      parent: "cameraPreview",
      className: "cameraPreview"
    };
    CameraPreview.start(cameraPreviewOptions);
    this.cameraActive = true;
  }

  async stopCamera() {
    await CameraPreview.stop();
    this.cameraActive = false;
  }

  async captureImage() {
    const CameraPreviewPictureOptions: CameraPreviewPictureOptions = {
      quality: 90

    }

    const result = await CameraPreview.capture(CameraPreviewPictureOptions)

    this.image = `data:image/jpeg;base64, $(result.value)`

    this.stopCamera()

  }

  flipCamera() {
    CameraPreview.flip()

  }

}
```

camera.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>camera</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div id="cameraPreview" class="cameraPreview">
    <div *ngIf="cameraActive">
      <img src="assets/icon/guide.png" class="image-overlay">
      <ion-button (click)="stopCamera()" expand="full" id="close">
        <ion-icon name="close-circle" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
      <ion-button (click)="captureImage()" expand="full" id="capture">
        <ion-icon name="camera" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
      <ion-button (click)="flipCamera()" expand="full" id="flip">
        <ion-icon name="repeat" slot="icon-only"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ion-img [src]="image" *ngIf="image && !cameraActive"></ion-img>
  <ion-button (click)="openCamera()" expand="full" *ngIf="!cameraActive">Open Camera</ion-button>
  <ion-button (click)="stopCamera()" expand="full" *ngIf="cameraActive">Open Camera</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

camera.scss

```
ion-content {
  --background: transparent !important;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.cameraPreview {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-overlay {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  width: 50%;
}

#capture {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 11;
}
#close {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: calc(50% - 175px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 11;
}
#flip {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: calc(50% + 125px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 11;
}

#close::part(native) {
  border-radius: 30px;
}
#capture::part(native) {
  border-radius: 30px;
}
#flip::part(native) {
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Apology opens camera preview without buttons

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import { CameraPreview, CameraPreviewPictureOptions } from '@capacitor-community/camera-preview'
```

instead of:

```
import { CameraPreviewOptions, CameraPreviewPictureOptions } from '@capacitor-community/camera-preview'
```